# Consequence of uncomplimentary MOSFETs in Hbridge

Tags: mosfet, components, h-bridge

I am constructing my own H-Bridge to control a high current motor (24V at 25A), as such I was looking to use high current MOSFETs for each quadrant of the H-bridge. My go too MOSFETs for these applications is the [IRF1405](http://www.redrok.com/MOSFET_IRF1405_55V_169A_5.3mO_Vth4.0_TO-220.pdf) unfortunately the manufacture for these MOSFETs do not offer a complementary P-channel equivalent. What will be the consequences of using a P-channel MOSFET  which is not exactly complement to the N-channel MOSFETS in my bridge.
Also does anyone have a suggestion for a complementary MOSFET pair which has similar specifications as the IRF1405? (RDS = 5.3mOhm ID= 169A)

The P-channel replacment I am considering is the [IPB120P04P4L](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPP_B_I120P04P4L_03-DS-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30432f69f146012f783b3b5a2e3f).
I have attached an image of my proposed H-Bridge for your reference.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you would need complementary transistors only for more linear/analog applications like in a (audio) power amplifier.

In an H-bridge you're using the MOSFETs as switches, they're either on or off. I would prefer to use FETs with the same Rdson (on resistance) though although as long as Rdson is low enough that might not even matter.

I would also pay attention to the threshold voltage but also here different Vt for NMOS and PMOS would not matter so much if you drive them properly with a large Vgs (which you should to make Rdson low).

So I would just try to find a suitable PMOS that can do the job and not worry about it not being complementary to the NMOS.

Answer (score 0):

my opinion is instead of using P-channal MOSFET at high side you can use same IRF1405 as this configuration. 
http://modularcircuits.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/image7.png

Comment: You should include the image directly in your answer. Also, what you suggest will obviously have a big impact on the driving side, and OP did not told us about this part of the circuit. So, maybe you could extend your answer by giving some hints about what solutions exist to drive the mosfet arrangement you suggested?